# Is it possible to use RDP with same browser data as admin?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, rdp

I just tried the RDP of windows 10 and it worked very well.
I have an admin account (named A), then I create another user (named B). When I use account B to log in RDP and open google chrome, I cannot access chrome data (history, cookies, passwords, ...), but it's like a newly installed chrome. So I want to ask is there any way that admin A and user B can use the same chrome data ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Chrome (probably for all the browsers) will store the browser data for different users in different location (location: `C:\Users\<current-user-name>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`). So if you logged in as a different user, it will use different browser data to start the browser.

If you really want to, probably you need to login your Chrome using the same Google account and then turn on the sync option, which is the easiest way.

Or another idea is that you can try to copy the other users browser data (location: `C:\Users\<other-user>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`) to your browser data location (location: `C:\Users\<your-user>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`) (really not recommended because you won't know how Chrome deals with the data and I'm not sure whether this works, I guess it won't work)

Comment: For some reason, I don't want to use the sync option.
And I try copy the folder like you said, but it doesnt work

Comment: Then I think except sharing the same account, proabbly there is no way to do what you want :(

Comment: I just found that there is a command line argument "--user-data-dir". What I did is I run chrome like this: "chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"", and, all the history is there, but there is no saved password, cookies.

Comment: Nice try. I guess cookies and password are not loaded because of security reasons. Otherwise, it's very dangerous that someone can easily steal others account info etc.